# Is Marshal.Copy too processor-intensive in this situation?

Tags: c#, marshalling, unmanaged

I am working on a realtime simulation model. The models are written in unmanaged code, but the models are controlled by C# managed code, called the ExecutiveManager. An ExecutiveManager runs multiple models at a time, and controls the timing of the running models (like if a model has a "framerate" of 20 per second, the executive will tell the models when to start it's next frame).

We are seeing a consistently high load on the CPU when running the simulation, it can get up to 100% and stay there on a machine that should be totally appropriate. I have used a processor profiler to determine where the issues are, and it pointed me to two methods: WriteMemoryRegion and ReadMemoryRegion. The ExecutiveManager makes the calls to these methods. Models have shared memory regions, and the ExecutiveManager is used to read and write these regions using these Methods. Both read and write make calls to Marshal.Copy, and my gut tells me that's where the issue is, but I don't want to trust my gut! We are going to do further testing to narrow things down more, but I wanted to do a quick sanity check on Marshal.Copy. WriteMemoryRegion and ReadMemoryRegion are called each frame, and furthermore they're called by each model in the ExecutiveManager, and each model typically has 6 shared regions. So for 10 models each with 6 regions running at 20 frames per second calling both WriteMemoryRegion and ReadMemoryRegion, that's 2400 calls of Marshal.Copy per second. Is this unreasonable, or could my problem lie elsewhere?

```
 public async Task ReadMemoryRegion(MemoryRegionDefinition g) {
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(g.Name)) {
            cache.Add(g.Name, mmff.CreateOrOpen(g.Name, g.Size));
        }
        var mmf = cache[g.Name];
        using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        using (var reader = brf.Create(stream)) {
            var buffer = reader.ReadBytes(g.Size);
            await WriteIcBuffer(g, buffer).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

private Task WriteIcBuffer(MemoryRegionDefinition g, byte[] buffer) {
        Marshal.Copy(buffer, 0, new IntPtr(g.BaseAddress), 
buffer.Length);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }

public async Task WriteMemoryRegion(MemoryRegionDefinition g) {
        if (!cache.ContainsKey(g.Name)) {
            if (g.Size > 0) {
                cache.Add(g.Name, mmff.CreateOrOpen(g.Name, g.Size));
            } else if (g.Size == 0){
                throw new EmptyGlobalException($@"Global {g.Name} not 
created as it does not contain any variables.");
            } else {
                throw new NegativeSizeGlobalException($@"Global {g.Name} 
not created as it has a negative size.");
            }
        }
        var mmf = cache[g.Name];
        using (var stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
        using (var writer = bwf.Create(stream)) {
            var buffer = await ReadIcBuffer(g);
            writer.Write(buffer);
        }
    }


private Task<byte[]> ReadIcBuffer(MemoryRegionDefinition g) {
        var buffer = new byte[g.Size];
        Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(g.BaseAddress), buffer, 0, g.Size);
        return Task.FromResult(buffer);
    }
```

I need to come up with a solution so that my processor isn't catching on fire. I'm very green in this area so all ideas are welcome. Again, I'm not sure Marshal.Copy is the issue, but it seems possible. Please let me know if you see other issues that could contribute to the processor problem.

Comment: Why do you use `async/await`? This is an unnecessary overhead. There's nothing async here.

Comment: Totally agree @Suiden. One of the programmers on this project does this sorry if thing constantly. Will remove.